# BIDS report design data tab - BIDS versions

Tags: bids

In business intelligence development studio I create a new report against the TFS OLAP cube.  Now from everything I have seen online this report should contain 3 tabs in report building functionality (Preview, Layout and Data).

Is there a specific version where creating a new report would have different tabs.  I am currently seeing Design & Preview only.  No layout and no Data tabs.  All of the report walkthroughs I have seen start from the data tab, manipulating dimensions etc.

[image]

Has anyone ran into this before, how do you resolve?

A more specific question would be - What version of BIDS contains the full functionality I am desiring here.

Answer (score 1):

The design has been changed in BIDS 2008.

Fix: in design, View >> Report Data (Ctrl+Alt+D)

Here you can create the dataset, datasource and parameters.